# How to call Verbose Imports?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

how to pass a **-v (verbose imports)** flag to the embedded Python interpreter. Have given in the documentation.
 I have tried with `pyinstaller -v wxpython.py`. It was displaying pyinstaller version. I am new to python, I don't know how to find these **hidden imports**, build the app with the **-v flag**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add the fllowing lines into xxx.spec (you can generate this file after run pyinstaller xxx.py and then delete the build/ and dist/ folders, re-run pyinstaller xxx.spec)

```
options = [ ('v', None, 'OPTION'), ('W ignore', None, 'OPTION') ]
a = Analysis( ...
            )
...
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      options,   <--- added line
      exclude_binaries=...
      )
```

If you got any errors, check [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/PyInstaller/verbose$20imports|sort:date/pyinstaller/XoFNMjXh498/ZXAdZUE8VFEJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/PyInstaller/verbose$20imports%7Csort:date/pyinstaller/XoFNMjXh498/ZXAdZUE8VFEJ)